# Captioning nested subfigures with subcaption

Tags: numbering, captions, subcaption

The following creates a figure with three images arranged appropriately. If I remove the two `\caption{}` lines, it numbers the main subfigures as I'd like, and keeping the two `\caption{}` lines puts subfigure letters in the right place for the sub-subfigures, but the letters are wrong.

How can I change the subfigure identification from a, b, c, d to a, b1, b2, b or something similar?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{wu8_wedges}
    \caption{With wedges.}
    \label{fig:wedges}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{wu8_flat1}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:flat1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{wu8_flat2}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:flat2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Without wedges}
    \label{fig:flat}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Interactions between the railcar and the man's feet.}
  \label{fig:interactions}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One possibility would be to manually adjust the counters and `\thesubfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{wu8_wedges}
    \caption{With wedges.}
    \label{fig:wedges}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}1}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{wu8_flat1}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:flat1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
      \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}
      \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}2}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{wu8_flat2}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:flat2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}
    \caption{Without wedges}
    \label{fig:flat}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Interactions between the railcar and the man's feet.}
  \label{fig:interactions}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: and especially do not print it out ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Gonzalo's answer, a more general method involves defining a `subsubfigure` environment:

```
\newenvironment{subsubfigure}[2][]{%
  \begin{subfigure}[#1]{#2}%
    \stepcounter{subsubfigure}%
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}.\roman{subsubfigure}}%
}{%
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}%
  \end{subfigure}%
}

\newcounter{subsubfigure}
```

Just make sure to reset the `subsubfigure` counter to 0 after each new `\begin{subfigure}`:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
    \setcounter{subsubfigure}{0}%         IMPORTANT
    \centering
    \begin{subsubfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img_1_a_i}
      \caption{}
    \end{subsubfigure}%
    \begin{subsubfigure}{0.5\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img_1_a_ii}
      \caption{}
    \end{subsubfigure}%
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
  % ...
  % more subfigures
  % ...
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

...Theoretically, one could patch the `subfigure` environment to do this for you, but I don't want to go down that rabbit hole just yet...

---

Example usage for original question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newenvironment{subsubfigure}[2][]{%
  \begin{subfigure}[#1]{#2}%
    \stepcounter{subsubfigure}%
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}.\roman{subsubfigure}}%
}{%
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}%
  \end{subfigure}%
}

\newcounter{subsubfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{wu8_wedges}
    \caption{With wedges.}
    \label{fig:wedges}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \setcounter{subsubfigure}{0}
    \begin{subsubfigure}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{wu8_flat1}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:flat1}
    \end{subsubfigure}
    \begin{subsubfigure}{\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{wu8_flat2}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:flat2}
    \end{subsubfigure}
    \caption{Without wedges}
    \label{fig:flat}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Interactions between the railcar and the man's feet.}
  \label{fig:interactions}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```