# How can different numbering style be used for nested subfigures?

Tags: numbering, captions, subfloats, nesting

I want to display a figure demonstrating 3 cases. The case1 and case2 are shown using single images each. But case 3 needs 3 images. I have used nested subfigure as follows: However the captions go as (a), (b), (d), (e), (f). I want to give captions (a) (b) and (c) for each case, and(i), (ii), (iii) for each image in case 3. How is that possible?
Thanks.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfigure[ ]{
\includegraphics[width=110px,height=85px]
{images/case1.eps}
\label{fig:case1}
}
\subfigure[ ]{
\includegraphics[width=110px,height=85px]
{images/case2.eps}
\label{fig:case2}
}
\subfigure[]{
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{images/case3a.eps}}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{images/case3b.eps}}
\subfigure[]{
\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{images/case3c.eps}}
}\
```

I also tried adding `\thesubfigure` and `\addtocounter` as per the link: 
*[Captioning nested subfigures with subcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78098/captioning-nested-subfigures-with-subcaption)*
It produced captions (a), (b), (c) for the 3 subfigures. But it gives (d) to all the 3 sub-subfigures in case3.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfigure[ ]{
\includegraphics[width=110px,height=85px]
{images/case1.eps}
\label{fig:case1}
}
\subfigure[ ]{
\includegraphics[width=110px,height=85px]
{images/case2.eps}
\label{fig:case2}
}
\subfigure[]{
\subfigure[]{
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}1}
\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{images/case3a.eps}}
\subfigure[]{
\addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}2}
\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{images/case3b.eps}}
\subfigure[]{
\addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}3}
\includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
{images/case3c.eps}}
\addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use the `subfigure` package, were numbering works a little bit different than in the linked question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfigure[ ]{
  \includegraphics[width=110px,height=85px]
  {images/case1}
  \label{fig:case1}
}
\subfigure[ ]{
  \includegraphics[width=110px,height=85px]
  {images/case2}
  \label{fig:case2}
}
\subfigure[]{
  \setcounter{subfigure}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\roman{subfigure})}
  \subfigure[]{
    \includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
    {images/case3a}}
  \subfigure[]{
    \includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
    {images/case3b}}
  \subfigure[]{
    \includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
    {images/case3c}}
  \label{fig:case3}
}
\caption{Main Figure}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig}, \ref{fig:case1}, \ref{fig:case2}, \ref{fig:case3}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

To have the figures all in one row comment the trailing line ends. Then you can pull the first two subfigure  captions deeper to align them with the third. This can be achieved by increasing `\subfigcapskip`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newlength{\addcapskip}%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \setlength{\addcapskip}{\subfigcapskip+9.5pt+\subfigbottomskip}%
  \addtolength{\subfigcapskip}{\addcapskip}%
  \subfigure[ ]{%
  \includegraphics[width=110px,height=85px]
  {images/case1}%
  \label{fig:case1}%
}%
\subfigure[ ]{%
  \includegraphics[width=110px,height=85px]
  {images/case2}%
  \label{fig:case2}%
}%
\addtolength{\subfigcapskip}{-\addcapskip}%
\subfigure[ ]{%
  \setcounter{subfigure}{0}%
  \renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\roman{subfigure})}%
  \subfigure[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
    {images/case3a}}%
  \subfigure[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
    {images/case3b}}%
  \subfigure[]{%
    \includegraphics[width=70px,height=60px]
    {images/case3c}}%
  \label{fig:case3}%
}%
\caption{Main Figure}\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig}, \ref{fig:case1}, \ref{fig:case2}, \ref{fig:case3}
\end{document}
```

[image: output with figures in a row]

One final remark: the `subfigure` package is superseded by the `subfig`  package, and both are no longer maintained. Currently, your best choice is the `subcaption` package. So if this is a new project, consider switching your tools.

Comment: One more question... suppose I want all of them to appear in one row. I can do so by removing the command \centering. But, in that case, I need to raise the images c(i), c(ii) and c(iii) up by a centimeter or so. How can I raise the figures?

Comment: You don't need to remove `\centering`, just remove spaces. Put `%` after each closing `}` of a subfigure, after the opening `{` of a subfigure, and so on. Then you will get one row of pictures, but note that the widths already sum to 430px.

Comment: yes, this works and this way I can get rid of the space between images too. But how can I raise the images up so that all 5 images will look aligned?