# How to increase counter on nested subfigure environment?

Tags: counters, subcaption, nesting

I would like to add an automatic numbering of nested subfigure environments.
I found the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78100/106251), which shows how I can manually add an additional Arabic number to my subsubfigure, but I would like to have this numbering on every "subfigure" inside another "subfigure" environment.

Is there any way to check `AtBeginEnvironment` if it is an nested environment and do this automatic?
And reset the subsubfigure-counter after the outer subfigure environment and reset the subfigure counter after the last nested subfigure?

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcounter{subsubfigure}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{figa}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.64\textwidth}
      \refstepcounter{subsubfigure} %TODO
      \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}\arabic{subsubfigure}} %TODO
      \centering
      \includegraphics{figb1}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:b1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
      \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1} %TODO
      \refstepcounter{subsubfigure} %TODO
      \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}\arabic{subsubfigure}} %TODO
      \centering
      \includegraphics{figb2}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:b2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1} %TODO
    \caption{Example}
  \end{subfigure}
  \setcounter{subsubfigure}{0} %TODO
  \caption[Examples]{Example \subref{fig:a}, Example \subref{fig:b1} and Example \subref{fig:b2}}
  \label{fig:Examples}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output of the figure part:
[image: Output of for the figure environment]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it could be done from `AtBeginEnvironment`, but you could define environments to automatically make the appropriate changes to the counters. In this example I took your code and added a `subsubfigure` environment, and also a `subsubfigures` environment in which all the subsubfigures from a single subfigure should be placed for the `subsubfigure` counter to be reset at the end of the subfigure.

It might not be the best implementation, but it does update the counters correctly.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcounter{subsubfigure}
\newenvironment{subsubfigures}{
  \refstepcounter{subfigure}
  }{
  \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}
  \setcounter{subsubfigure}{0}
}
\newenvironment{subsubfigure}[1]{
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}\arabic{subsubfigure}}
  \begin{subfigure}{#1}
    \refstepcounter{subsubfigure}
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}
  }{
  \end{subfigure}
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{test}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{figa}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.64\textwidth}
  \begin{subsubfigures}
    \begin{subsubfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figb1}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:b1}
    \end{subsubfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subsubfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figb2}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:b2}
    \end{subsubfigure}
    \end{subsubfigures}
    \caption{Example}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Examples]{Example \subref{fig:a}, Example \subref{fig:b1} and Example \subref{fig:b2}}
  \label{fig:Examples}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.64\textwidth}
  \begin{subsubfigures}
    \begin{subsubfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figb1}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:a1}
    \end{subsubfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subsubfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figb2}
      \caption{}
      \label{fig:a2}
    \end{subsubfigure}
    \end{subsubfigures}
    \caption{Example}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{figa}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Examples]{Example \subref{fig:a1}, Example \subref{fig:a2} and Example \subref{fig:b}}
  \label{fig:Examples2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]